# How do I wait before executing the next line of code?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need the script to stop and wait 3 seconds before executing the code that follows (`console.log('2 select question')`).

```
var i = 0,
    count = 5;
function f() {

    if (i < count) {
        i++;
        console.log('Continue 1')
        setTimeout(f, 1000);

    } if (i >= count) {
        console.log('2 select question')
        console.log('3 select answer')
        i = 0;
    }
}
f();
```

Comment: `if` -> `else if`

Comment: @jabaa is correct.  You want the function to set the timer or reset "i", but not do both.  Without the "else if" logic the timer will never stop.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I don't know if i undrestand you but try this :

```
var i = 0,
    count = 5;
function f() {

    if (i < count) {
        i++;
        console.log('Continue 1')
        setTimeout(f, 1000);

    } 
   else if (i >= count) {
        console.log('2 select question')
        console.log('3 select answer')
        i = 0;
    }
}
f();
```